# Python: Removing values from a dict which are in range() of each other

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to remove values from a dict that are within 2 digits of each other, while keeping the smallest value of the similar values. For the dict below, this would mean that only group2 and group3 are removed, leaving group1 because 54, 55, and 56 are all within two digits of each other, and because 54 is the smallest of these three similar values, it remains in the dict.

```
words = {
        "the": 10,
        "group1": 54,
        "then": 40,
        "now": 50,       
        "group2": 55,            
        "it": 60,
        "group3": 56
        }
```

to -

```
words = {
        "the": 10,
        "group1": 54,
        "then": 40,
        "now": 50,                   
        "it": 60
        }
```

What I have so far is:

```
new_dict = {}    
words_dup = []

for word, value in words.items():
    words_dup.append(value)

for word, value in words.items():
    for item in words_dup:
        if item-value in range(-2,2): 
            words_dup.remove(item)
            new_dict[word] = value
```

My approach is sloppy and is only removing random key, values from the dict. What is a better approach to solving this, one that perhaps doesn't require having to create both a new list and dict like I did above. Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of "similar"?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: I have edited the question to include what similar means in this context. I apologize for the being unclear. For some reason, this problem has been hard for me to both solve and explain, even though it comes across relatively simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is better? It's O(n^2), but I doubt you can get better than this without a more complex data structure:

```
words = {
    "the": 10,
    "group1": 54,
    "then": 40,
    "now": 50,       
    "group2": 55,            
    "it": 60,
    "group3": 56
}

new_dict = {key: val for key, val in words.items() 
            if all(abs(val - v) > 2 for k, v in words.items() if k != key)}

print(new_dict)
# {'the': 10, 'then': 40, 'now': 50, 'it': 60}
```

If keeping the smallest element is required:

```
new_dict = {key: val for key, val in words.items()
            if all(not 0 < val - v <= 2 for k, v in words.items() if k != key)}
print(new_dict)
# {'the': 10, 'group1': 54, 'then': 40, 'now': 50, 'it': 60}
```

Comment: @Sean I just noticed you changed the question, will edit.

Comment: This works great and really makes me realize I have a LOT to learn. I will be studying up on your much more pythonic and programmatic way of solving this. Each part and piece makes sense, but putting them all together still slightly boggles me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sean No problem. Also, in your updated question, you wanted to keep the smallest element, so I updated my answer to accommodate for that.